# Can add adsense on pythonanywhere free plan?

Tags: adsense, pythonanywhere

Can add adsense on pythonanywhere free plan?
I'm developing a blog using django and a want to host it on pythonanywhere free plan, but a wanna to add adsense, so I would like to now if Pythonanywhere Acept.

Answer (score 1):

PythonAnywhere dev here. We're happy for you to do that. No problem.